# spring data and mongodb : issue in updating existing document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

creating a document with status as pending and generated-token then send mail

and immediately after sending mail retrieving document by generated-token value and changing the previous status pending to unverified.

Even though for updating the document status, first retrieved the existing document and then only updating it, still end up in creating two different documents for both the status.

```
@Document
public class VerificationInfo {         
    private LoginInfo user; 
    private String token; 
    private String verificationStatus = VerificationStatus.PENDING.getVerificationStatus();
}
```

daoService

```
public void updateStatus(VerificationInfo verificationToken, String status) {
        VerificationInfo vt = verificationRepository.findByToken(verificationToken.getToken()).get(0);
        vt.setVerificationStatus(status);
        verificationRepository.save(vt);
    }
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface VerificationRepository extends MongoRepository<VerificationInfo, String> {
     List<VerificationInfo> findByToken(String token);
     List<VerificationInfo> findByUser(LoginInfo user);
}
```

db entries

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e7486664e197f3d745b17"), "token" : "c82907b7-e13e-484d-89cf-92ea394b6f6d", "verificationStatus" : "pending", "_class" : "com.models.VerificationInfo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e748b664e197f3d745b18"), "token" : "c82907b7-e13e-484d-89cf-92ea394b6f6d", "verificationStatus" : "unverified", "_class" : "com.models.VerificationInfo" }
```

Comment: what is the status printing in updateStatus()

Comment: @varman set as unverified, its priniting as unverified only. Even in DB also its saving correct value, but the only problem is rather than updating the existing document its creating new document

Comment: Don't you have any unique id?

Comment: is your document updated with  any id?

Comment: by default mongodb is creating _id. 
otherwise does it required to have unique ?

Comment: yes, its creating new document with new object _id, updated code with db entries

Comment: If you have any doubts, feel free to comment

Comment: already upvoted @varman

Answer (score 1):

If the status is correct, the problem with you *identification of the document (_id)*.

```
public class VerificationInfo {
    @Id
    ObjectId _id;
    // Other fields
}
```

Here we set a unique id to each document. So when you create a object, it will create a new document. If the _id already exists in database, then it will update the document based on the particular id.

**1. There is no _id present in the model class**

You  `extends MongoRepository<VerificationInfo, String>`, the second parameter is the type of `id`. But there is no any `id` found in your model class. (Usually we use `ObjectId`, but `String` also can be given)

**2. It will always create new document when you get data from frontend**

Since you don't have id, when you pass a data to `updateStatus(VerificationInfo verificationToken, String status)`, it will create new `id` and set the data, that's why you always getting new document.

Suppose you are sending the data with existing `id`, then the existing document will be updated based on given `id`